# Metal Shading Language - struct does not provide a subscript operator

Tags: macos, metal

I have a `struct` in my `metal` file:

```
struct Vects
{
    float3 position[100];
};
```

which will be used to hold the buffer data:

```
kernel void compute(texture2d<float, access::write> output [[texture(0)]],
                    constant float &time [[buffer(0)]],
                    constant mouseInput &mouse [[buffer(1)]],
                    constant Vects &vects [[buffer(2)]],//<--- Vects
                    uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
...
sceneSDF(origin, vects);
...
}
```

which

```
float sceneSDF(float3 cotu,Vects vects) {

    float a;

    for(int i = 1; i < 3 ; i++){

        float3 u = vects[i-1].position;//<-- error!
        float3 v = vects[i].position;//<-- error!
        a = min(fSphere(cotu + u,0.7),fSphere(cotu + v,0.7));

    }
    return a;
}
```

I got an error at `float3 u` and `float3 v` that

> Type 'Vects' does not provide a subscript operator

How can I resolve this?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious accident. taken out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got your order for dot notation and array subscript mixed up in your case. These lines:

```
float3 u = vects[i-1].position;
float3 v = vects[i].position;
```

Should be:

```
float3 u = vects.position[i-1];
float3 v = vects.position[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need write like this:

```
 float3 u = vects[i-1].position[i-1];//<-- error!
 float3 v = vects[i].position;//<-- error!
```

because vects is not array, so you can't use it that way.The type of u,v is float3, it's the same with vects.position[i]